# popen and system behaves unexpectedly with multiple quoted file paths

Tags: c++, system, popen

I am trying to execute a dos command from within my C++ program, however soon as I add quotes to the output filepath (of a redirection) the command no longer gets executed and returns instantly.  I've shown an example below of a path without spaces, but since paths may have spaces and thus be quoted for the shell to understand it properly I need to solve this dilemma - and I'm trying to get the simplest case working first.

i.e.

The following **WORKS**:

```
sprintf(exec_cmd,"\"C:/MySQL Server 5.5/bin/mysqldump.exe\" -u%s -p%s %s > C:/backup.bak",user,password,db_name);
system(exec_cmd);
```

The following does **NOT** work (notice the quotes around the output):

```
sprintf(exec_cmd,"\"C:/MySQL Server 5.5/bin/mysqldump.exe\" -u%s -p%s %s > \"C:/backup.bak\"",user,password,db_name);
system(exec_cmd);
```

I'm guessing it is choking somewhere.  I've tried the same "exec_cmd" in popen to no avail.

Any help/advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `popen` and `system` are both very dangerous interfaces which are easy to use sloppily and hard to use correctly. I would highly recommend using a saner method for calling external programs - either `fork` and `exec` if you're using cygwin, or otherwise whatever the WinAPI function to start a program is...

Comment: You clearly state that you're running in C++, so do not tag your question as C.

Comment: People just should stop using `system` for anything non-trivial. Setting up a proper child process is easier then fighting bizarre quoting rules of antiquated shells.

Comment: @DeadMG: You're right, my bad.  However it is legacy C code in C++ and it seems soon as someone sees sprintf in a C++ question everyone gets derailed on C code stuck in C++. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your shell (`cmd.exe`) allows redirection to a file name with spaces. I couldn't make my `command.com` from DOS 6.22 accept it (I don't have a `cmd.exe` nearby to test).

Anyway, you can use the [`--result-file`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_result-file) option to pass the redirection to the command itself.

```
mysqldump ... --result-file="file name" ...
```

Comment: To think I was going to just put foo.exe instead; good thing I didn't change the exe name!  That will work perfect thanks.  For the sake of education I'll leave the question up though and try using fork/exec also, as I know doubt will come across this problem somewhere down the road again.